# how to scrape hindi text from web using php

Tags: php, unicode, page-curl

Here i am trying to scrape data from the web (in url) that is in hindi but I am getting response like this

> \u093f\u0938\

How to decode this unicode? Please suggest me what to do my script in PHP.

This script is working correctly with english text so what is happening with english. I have already scraped data with this script. I know this response is dev nagri unicode but how to decode it.

I am new in php problem thanks in advance

```
$i= 1;
for($i; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    $html file_get_contents("http://www.jagran.com/jokes/child/jokes-1262211".$i.".html");
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
    $item = array();
    $articles = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
         $item['msg'] = (strlen($node->nodeValue) > 20 ? $node->nodeValue : '');
         $item['cat_id'] = 1;
         if($item['msg'] !="")
         $articles[] = array_unique($item);
    }
    $articles = json_encode($articles);
    print_r($articles);
}
```

Comment: Place in header <metacharset="utf-8">

Comment: That response is _not_ unicode, which is exactly your problem. It is escaped, since the transport layer or some other element uses a different encoding. Could it be that your own system does not have phps multi byte extension loaded and configured?

Comment: @ arkascha this is devnagri code for hindi words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **PHPhil**'s answer is good and I upvoted it. I edited the code as it does not work just to execute the php part - instead it is important to add the right meta tag (see the code below) to show the devnagari properly. Also I wanted to correct the mistake with the missing "=". Unfortunately my edit was rejected so I have to add a new answer with the code corrections.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php

$i= 1;
for($i; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.jagran.com/jokes/child/jokes-1262211".$i.".html");
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
    $item = array();
    $articles = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
         $item['msg'] = (strlen($node->nodeValue) > 20 ? $node->nodeValue : '');
         $item['cat_id'] = 1;
         if($item['msg'] !="")
         $articles[] = array_unique($item);
    }
    $articles = json_encode($articles, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
//--------------------add-this---------------------^
    print_r($articles);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

f you are running PHP 5.4 or greater, pass the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` parameter when calling json_encode.

```
$i= 1;
for($i; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    $html file_get_contents("http://www.jagran.com/jokes/child/jokes-1262211".$i.".html");
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
    $item = array();
    $articles = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
         $item['msg'] = (strlen($node->nodeValue) > 20 ? $node->nodeValue : '');
         $item['cat_id'] = 1;
         if($item['msg'] !="")
         $articles[] = array_unique($item);
    }
    $articles = json_encode($articles, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
//--------------------add-this---------------------^
    print_r($articles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. You receive the signs: ि and स

First you can try is google for the character and you will find the devnagari meaning of the chars:

https://www.google.de/#q=%5Cu093f

https://www.google.de/#q=%5Cu0938

If you want to show unicode in html you have to change the encoding from /u0123 to &#x123. See here:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>These are two chars in devnagari &#x93f;&#x938;<p>
</body>
</html>
```

But as you are wanting to scrape Hindi you should start learning how to read and handle unicode. Next question is, how you want to process with your result.